# Velocity Template - regular expressions

Tags: regex, velocity

I just started using velocity for a new job and I really don't like what I have found already.  At this point, i would actually prefer freemarker =X.
Anyways, i'm trying to do a regular expression and i saw [this little bit (search "regular expression")](http://wiki.dbsight.com/index.php?title=Velocity_Template_Help), but that isn't quite the implementation I am doing.

I do not have any access to the java so that option of writing something custom to do this stuff is not there (i'm not even sure if that is possible).

This is what i have right now:

```
#set ( $envCheck = "(localhost|staging|qa|cms)\\.site" )
#set ( $envCheck = $envCheck.matches($gatewayURL) )
```

but `$envCheck` always just comes out as "false".  `$gatewayURL` is defined on the page as well, so that is not the issue.

is this even possible?  i was reading that any regexp method that the java String class has is available in the velocity template.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `$gatewayURL` is somethign like this:

```
#set ( $gatewayURL = "localhost.site" )
```

Then:

```
#set ( $envCheck = "(localhost|staging|qa|cms)\.site" )
#set ( $envCheck = $gatewayURL.matches($envCheck) )
```

No need to mask backslash, and you should be calling `matches()` on `gatewayURL`, not regular expression.

Velocity doesn't have its own regexp implementation, it just passes parameters you provide to corresponding native java methods, that's all. So you have pretty much full Java SDK at your disposal.

Comment: is this for a specific version of velocity?  We're running 1.4 here (a bunch of legacy crap...)  I can't seem to get your regexp version working.

also, after writing my initial comment, i did find out that the object has access to the java methods, depending on the object type

Comment: @dtan Sorry I am not sure about 1.4, it is too old. There were some  drastic changes since then...

Comment: that's pretty generic Velocity.  It should work in 1.4.  But of course, the JDK must be at least 1.4.  (or whatever the relevant version is for the method calls you are making).

Comment: @will - i'm not entirely sure what the stack is at work, but i just know there is a LOT of legacy code since this system was first built in the early 2000s and for whichever reasons they did not upgrade as new releases came out.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is way late but probably still good as a reference for Velocity users encountering the same issue.

We use Velocity 1.5 (too big a task to upgrade to 1.7/1.6 as they broke too many templates) and encountered the same issue.  The answer above would not work - backlash without escape (\) results in Lexical error and with escape (\\) return false always as I think it is being interpreted literally.  The right way to solve it is by using single quote instead of double quotes when defining the regex expression so Velocity would not attempt to interpret the string that is meant for Java.

```
#set ( $envCheck = '(localhost|staging|qa|cms)\.site' )
#set ( $envCheck = $envCheck.matches($gatewayURL) )
```

Comment: lolz. gotta love the single vs double quote tricks :). If i still worked with velocity (thank god i don't), i would try to give you the answer but I can't verify anything.

Comment: No problem. After years of surviving JSP, Velocity is not so bad... :-)