# Regex not working in Velocity Template

Tags: java, regex, velocity

I tried this in Test.java

```
String regex = "<\\s*br\\s*/*\\s*>";

String test1 = "< br/ >";

System.out.println(test.replaceAll(regex, " "));`
```

But when I try the same thing in a velocity template
    `

```
#set($brRegex = "<\\s*br\\s*/*\\s*>")
#set($imageDescription = $imageDescription.replaceAll($brRegex, " "))`
```

And:

```
#set($imageDescription = $imageDescription.replaceAll("<\\s*br\\s*/*\\s*>", " "))`
```

Both don't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to SO, RMVinodh.

Comment: Thanks Brian, SO is a great place.

Answer (score 9):

Omit the extra backslashes.  No need to escape them.  See [Velocity Template - regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103021/velocity-template-regular-expressions)

```
#set($brRegex = "<\s*br\s*/*\s*>")
#set($imageDescription = $imageDescription.replaceAll($brRegex, " "))`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I removed the extra backslashes, this is what I see. Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 20.  Encountered: "s" (115), after : "\"<\\"

Comment: It looks to me that the error suggests that there are still two slashes before the `s`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is what I have now     

`
        
    #set($brRegex = "<\s*br\s*/*\s*>")
    #set($returnd = "< br >")
    $returnd.matches($brRegex)
`

Comment: I am currently using #set($regex = "< *br */? *>") to match <br> tags and this works, but this isn't as robust as what I would have wanted.