# Velocity - searching within a String containing XML

Tags: regex, xml, search, velocity

I'm currently working on a velocity template which should be configurable using an XML file.

I was able to read the file into a variable. In order to check the configuration I would now need to find certain string in the variable. In some cases the search string might be a Regular Expression.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103021/velocity-template-regular-expressions) I understood that I can use `.matches()` to search for a RegEx. But whatever I tried (cf. my "test code" below) I get only "false" returned, even if I just try to search one of the tags.

```
<html>
    <body>
## this example is intended to test searching regular expressions

## let's start with a simple example:

#set( $simpleText = "This is the string where I will try to find a substring." )
#set( $searchStr = "string" )

1 $simpleText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## this returns false as .matches() only returns true if the parameter $searchStr (could be regular expression) matches the ENTIRE string ($simpleText)

#set( $searchStr = ".*string.*" )       ## .* at the beginning and the end of the search string means any character can be before and after the 'real' search string

2 $simpleText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## this returns true, so adding .* at the beginning and the end of the search string seems to work.

## let's now move on to strings containing XML (as this is the real use case)

#set( $xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemTypes>
    <ItemType>
        <Display>L1 Items</Display>
        <Fields>
            <FieldLabel>Project ID</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Name</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Description</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Assigned</FieldLabel>
        <Fields>
    </ItemType>
</ItemTypes>' )

3 $xmlText<BR>                          ## when printing a string containing XML tags those tags will not be visible in the printout (probably because they are interpreted as kind of html tags...)

#set( $escapedXmlText = $escapeTool.xml($xmlText) )  ## escapeTool will ensure that the tags will also be printed (visible)

4 $escapedXmlText<BR>                   ## this printout will also display the tags

## let's now try to find the string 'Display' in xmlText the same way as we did in the simple example at the beginning:

#set( $searchStr = '.*Display.*')

5 $xmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>          ## returns false but WHY?
6 $escapedXmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## returns false but WHY?

    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea why the printout 5 and 6 at the end both return false?

Comment: Your error begins with trying to parse XML with regular expressions. Don't do that, ever. It does not work. Use an XML parser. There is [XmlTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/XmlTool.html), which looks promising, and there also is a whole [section devoted to working with XML in the Deveoper's Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html#velocity-and-xml)

Comment: First of all, thx for your input. I also came across the XmlTool stuff but if I understood correctly this would require access to the environment providing the context.

Comment: In my case the Velocity engine is included in an application and I doubt I can influence the context in any way. However, after some further investigation I found out that . may not match line terminators. To also let . match those line terminators you need to enable "DOTALL mode" which can be done using "the embedded flag expression (?s)". Since I never came across these things I'm still not entirely sure but it seems working.

Comment: Stop trying to parse XML with regular expressions, you are wasting your time. It always looks like *"just another tiny thing to fix and then it works"*, but that's an illusion. It will never work. It cannot work. Do yourself a favor and get it out of your head.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer myself, although I'm not entirely sure (so happy to get any feedback).
Below my test example extended by a couple of lines (also containing comments with my findings):

```
<html>
    <body>
## this example is intended to test searching regular expressions

## let's start with a simple example:

#set( $simpleText = "This is the string where I will try to find a substring." )
#set( $searchStr = "string" )

1 $simpleText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## this returns false as .matches() only returns true if the parameter $searchStr (could be regular expression) matches the ENTIRE string ($simpleText)

#set( $searchStr = ".*string.*" )     ## .* at the beginning and the end of the search string means any character can be before and after the 'real' search string

2 $simpleText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## this returns true, so adding .* at the beginning and the end of the search string seems to work.

## let's now move on to strings containing XML (as this is the real use case)

#set( $xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemTypes>
    <ItemType>
        <Display>L1 Items</Display>
        <Fields>
            <FieldLabel>Project ID</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Name</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Description</FieldLabel>
            <FieldLabel>Assigned</FieldLabel>
        <Fields>
    </ItemType>
</ItemTypes>' )

3 $xmlText<BR>                          ## when printing a string containing XML tags those tags will not be visible in the printout (probably because they are interpreted as kind of html tags...)

#set( $escapedXmlText = $escapeTool.xml($xmlText) )  ## escapeTool will ensure that the tags will also be printed (visible)

4 $escapedXmlText<BR>                   ## this printout will also display the tags

## let's now try to find the string 'Display' in xmlText the same way as we did in the simple example at the beginning:

#set( $searchStr = '.*Display.*')

5 $xmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>          ## returns false, obviously because . does not match "line terminators" (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
6 $escapedXmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## also returns false

## on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt you can find the following info:
## "The regular expression . matches any character except a line terminator unless the DOTALL flag is specified."
## https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL says:
## "Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s)."
## and https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-write-embedded-flag-expression/ finally says that embedded flag expression are to be provided at the beginning of the regex.
## So, let's now try (this time also including some special characters like '<', '>', '/'):

#set( $searchStr = '(?s).*<Display>L1 Items</Display>.*')

7 $xmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>          ## FINALLY RETURNS TRUE!!
8 $escapedXmlText.matches($searchStr)<BR>   ## still return false as in the escaped XML special characters like '<' are replaced/escaped

    </body>
</html>
```

So, starting the regex with (?s) seems to do the trick!